# How to define HashMap<String, List<Object>> property in swagger yml?

Tags: java, typescript, yaml, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am using swagger to generate classes in Java and Type script. 
I have problem defining map property with list of objects as value. I tried to define as follows:

```
DataMap
type: object
additionalProperties:
 #type: array -- This config does not work.
  $ref: '#/definitions/Data'
```

Above yml definition generated  following code in java:

```
  class DataMap extends HashMap<String, Data> {
    }
```

How can I configure yml to generate key with list of data ? something like following class:

```
 class DataMap extends HashMap<String, List<Data>> {
        }
```

or

```
 class DataInfo {
     Map<String, List<Data>> dataMap;
   }
```

Is this possible with swagger 2.0? I am thinking of defining another DataList class which extends ArrayList then use this class as value to Map.

**--------------UPDATE & ANSWER-----------**

Thanks @nickb

I am using swagger-codegen-maven-plugin version 2.2.1 and yml definition to generate map as follows:

```
 DataInfo
    type: object
    properties:
    dataMap:
     type: object
     additionalProperties:
        type: array 
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Data'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using Swagger codegen v2.1.6 with the following model definitions:

```
 foo:
    properties:
      baz:
        type: string
  bar:
    properties:
      map:
        type: object
        additionalProperties:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/definitions/foo'
```

This generates a `Bar` Java class with the following field:

```
Map<String, List<Foo>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Foo>>();
```

If you're seeing different behavior, you could've stumbled into a regression. Try testing earlier versions, or specifically see if 2.1.6 correctly generates this model.

Comment: Awesome, I will check my swagger library. thanks @nickb

Comment: The latest stable version of Swagger Codegen is 2.2.2: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases. Please consider upgrade to the latest stable version to get bug fixes and enhancements.

Comment: @nickb  Thank you very much, After changing the definition as you suggested it works.

Comment: @wing328 I am using 2.2.1 Thanks