# How to describe a map with object keys in OpenAPI/Swagger?

Tags: rest, swagger, openapi

In my REST API, I want to use a hashmap `Map<Foo, List<Bar>>` where `Foo` and `Bar` are user-defined classes. How to describe such a map in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027428/how-to-define-hashmapstring-listobject-property-in-swagger-yml

Comment: thank u Sudhir, but it is in the form "Map<String, List<Foo>> map" but i want it in "Map<Foo, List<Foo>> map"

Comment: Can u please share a example of how it can be done

Answer (score 3):

OpenAPI (Swagger) only supports maps with string keys such as:

```
{
  "en":  "Hello",
  "fr":  "Bonjour"

   ^^ key is a string
}
```

It is not possible to define maps with non-string keys, such as `Map<Foo, Bar>`. You can submit a feature request in the OpenAPI Specification repository: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues.

The most you can do is define your hashmap as just `type: object`, which means an arbitrary object.

Comment: OpenAPI schema definitions are based on JSON Schema, and JSON hashmaps use string keys. How do you think `Map<Foo, Bar>` would be represented in JSON?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `additionalProperties`
See [docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/)

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Messages:        # <---- map
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        type: string
```

It represents in json as:

```json
{
  "Alex":  "Hello",
  "Ann":  "Hi!"

   ^^ key is a string
}
```